# Is there a way to delete bones and transfer weight to parent bone

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I have an armature with a lot of bones that each have some weight paint on a part part of the body, I want to delete pretty much all the bones and transfer their weight to their parent bone.
I cant use vertex weight mix cuz it would take a long time and would be complicated since there are a lot of bones

Answer (score 1):

### Python script

In the lines 3-5 specify your armature's name, the `source` bone to remove (it will be removed together with all of its children - and their children and so on, recursively). The weights will be transferred (by addition, which Blender automatically clamps in 0..1 range so it won't add up to more than 1) to the `target` bone.

```
import bpy

arm = bpy.data.armatures['Skeleton']
source = arm.bones['upperFaceRig']
target = arm.bones['head']

def transfer_weights(source, target, obj):
    source_group = obj.vertex_groups.get(source.name)
    if source_group is None:
        return
    source_i = source_group.index
    target_group = obj.vertex_groups.get(target.name)
    if target_group is None:
        target_group = obj.vertex_groups.new(name=target.name)
        
    for v in obj.data.vertices:
        for g in v.groups:
            if g.group == source_i:
                target_group.add((v.index,), g.weight, 'ADD')
    obj.vertex_groups.remove(source_group)
    

def remove_bone(source, target):
    for o in bpy.data.objects:
        transfer_weights(source, target, o)
    edit_bone = arm.edit_bones.get(source.name)
    arm.edit_bones.remove(edit_bone)


def main():
    for bone in source.children_recursive:
        remove_bone(bone, target)
    remove_bone(source, target)


main()
```

Based on [Exporting weight and bone elements to a text file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/74461/60486)

Comment: I'm getting this error with this script:
line 32, in remove_bone
TypeError: ArmatureEditBones.remove(): error with argument 1, "bone" -  Function.bone does not support a 'None' assignment EditBone type

Comment: @0x_Anakin can you upload a file with the problem?

Comment: It's a genesis 8 female, I just replace Skeleton with `Genesis 8 Female` which is the armature name the other 2 are the same